# Optional argument for newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, optional-arguments, arguments

Suppose we define the following macros:

`\newcommand*{\G}[1][G]{\mathbb #1}`
`\newcommand*{\Cop}[1][]{\Delta_{#1}}`

For the first one, if we use $\G$ it produces in the pdf what $\mathbb{G}$ does and if we use $\G[H]$, then in this case it produces what $\mathbb{H}$ does. Now, if we use $\Cop[\G]$ then it produces $\Delta_{\mathbb{G}}$ as expected. But the problem is, whenever we use $\Cop[\G[H]]$ to produce the result of $\Delta_{mathbb{H}}$ there is the following error:

**Argument of \\G has an extra }**

What is actually wrong in there?

Comment: if you use `newcommand` then you need to "hide" inner `[]` so `\Cop[{\G[H]}]`  or you could use `\NewDocumentCommand` which matches nested `[]` pairs while looking for the optional argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so very much!! Works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional arguments aren't quite the same as mandatory ones.  They start with a `[`, and they are delimited **by the next `]`** (that's important).  When you do

```
\Cop[\G[H]]
%   1  2 34
```

`\Cop` is processed first, and its optional argument starts with the first `[` (1), and is delimited by the next `]` (3), so its argument is what's between `[` (1) and `]` (3), that is, `\G[H`.  Replacing `\Cop` by its definition with the argument:

```
\Delta_{\G[H}]
```

and you can see where it goes wrong.

To solve it, either "hide" the inner argument in braces:

```
\Cop[{\G[H]}]
```

or use `ltcmd` to define the commands:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \Cop { O{G} } {\mathbb{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \G { O{} } {\Delta_{#1}}
```

(`ltcmd` has an extra layer of parsing which ensures that `[` and `]` are balanced within optional arguments).

Comment: It should be `\mathbb{#1}`

Comment: @egreg Good catch, thanks!